# How can I give my portable VB.NET application file read/write permissions without Administrator access?

Tags: vb.net, permissions, file-permissions, administrator

I am developing a portable application that needs to create, modify and read various files (create logs, configs, export .jpg and .csv files, etc.) next to it. This application has to work from whatever directory the user places it into. I don't want to have Administrator access as a requirement, because many people don't have it on their workplace computers, and it can look understandably suspicious. Problem is, Windows usually prevents file creation for applications launched from non-administrative accounts under most directories (like Program Files). I cannot have my application write it's additional files to some other directory with full permissions under any account (like My Documents), because it will defeat the whole point of portability.

Judging from what I've googled I would think that what I want is impossible, but I've seen (and have on my computer) dozens of applications, most of them portable, that do not require Administrator account or access, which can be launched from pretty much any directory, and they read/write files without any problems. So evidently it is possible, but I can't seem to find any information on how they achieve this.

Can someone advice me how to best approach this issue?

Comment: You can only write files that your user has write access to.  Portable applications can still write to user-specific directories.

Comment: Then how come there are so many portable/install-able applications that can be run with non-administrator accounts, and are still able to create files under C:/Program Files?

Comment: That is not possible (unless they change ACLs as admin on install, which would be evil).

Comment: I don't know what's possible and what's not, I'm just saying that I have many applications like that on my computer... Like, for example, games under C:/Program Files, that create logs, save files, etc. under the same directory, and do not require to be run as administrator or from an administrator account. So how do they manage it? Because it seems to be a very common thing.

Comment: Older games generally require Windows to run them as admin for compatibility reasons.  Also check the folder's ACLs.

Comment: Why don't you write your log files under `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`. which is normally `c:\ProgramData`.  That doesn't require a specific user account and shouldn't need Admin permissions IIRC.  See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-folderlocations-programdata)

Comment: I want to have everything in the same folder as the executable itself, which is the whole point of portability...